# Неправильный внешний ключ

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть такое объявление таблицы:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users_online;
CREATE TABLE users_online(
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    lastvisittime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_list(user_id) ON DELETE SET NULL

);
```

Но база ругается что ключ неправильно сформирован. Но я не пойму что не так? Можете помочь?

Comment: А как именно ругается база ?

Comment: А, все разобрался. Я же ставлю что поле не NULL и тут же пишу что при удалении SET NULL.

Comment: используйте mysql workbench

Comment: @Jean-Claude, спасибо за совет.